# what is the result of left outer join if second table used in join not having any records?

Tags: sql

i am having two tables sd_billing_h and QM_TESTCERTIFICATEFORMATCUST_T .
First table is having all billing no's.
and in my second table will contain billing no whose test certificate is created.

now i want to retrieve only those billing no for which test certificate is not created.
billing_no,plant_code is a primary key of my first table.And Doc_no and billing no is a primary key of my second table.
and in my second table one indicator column is there which shows test certificate is created for that invoice no.
my doubt is if second table is not having any records,and if i use left outer join like

```
SELECT A.BILLING_NO AS INVOICE_NO,A.FYEAR 
FROM 
    SD_BILLING_H A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    QM_TESTCERTIFICATEFORMATCUST_T B
ON
    A.PLANT_CODE=B.PLANT_CODE
    A.COMPANY_CODE=B.COMPANY_CODE
    A.FYEAR=B.FYEAR
    A.BILLING_NO=B.INVOICE_NO 
WHERE 
    A.PLANT_CODE=@PLANT_CODE 
    AND A.COMPANY_CODE=@COMPANY_CODE 
    AND A.FYEAR=@FYEAR
    AND B.TEST_CERT_IND=1
```

will this result all billing_no from first table.

Answer (score 1):

This condition in the `where` clause turns the `left outer join` into an `inner join`, because `NULL` values will always fail:

```
AND B.TEST_CERT_IND = 1
```

The condition is on the second table, so the value -- when there is no match -- will be `NULL`.

The normal solution is to move such conditions to the `on` clause:

```
ON A.PLANT_CODE=B.PLANT_CODE AND
   A.COMPANY_CODE=B.COMPANY_CODE AND
   A.FYEAR=B.FYEAR AND
   A.BILLING_NO=B.INVOICE_NO AND
   B.TEST_CERT_IND = 1
```

(I've helpfully added `AND`s between the clauses.)

Note that conditions on the first table remain in the `where` clause; that is where you filter on the first table.

Comment: I want to retrieve all billing no from first table,and if any billing no have entry in both table then i don't want that billing no in result.so,will i use left outer join or some any other solution

Comment: @AshwiniAgivale Then you need to move your `B.TEST_CERT_IND=1` condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `JOIN` clause